# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'getBoardSize' of 'getContext(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: typescript, svelte

I'm new to svelte and getting error in `getContext()`. Please help

setting context -

```
  import type { ChangeEventHandler } from "svelte/elements";
  import { setContext, onMount } from "svelte";

  let selectBoardSize: HTMLSelectElement;
  let boardSize: number;

  setContext('boardSize', {
    getBoardSize : () => boardSize
  })

    const handleSelectChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLSelectElement> = () => {
        boardSize = Number(selectBoardSize.value)
    }

    onMount(() => {
        boardSize = Number(selectBoardSize.value)
    })
```

getting context -

```
    import { getContext, onMount } from "svelte";

    const { getBoardSize } = getContext('boardSize') // error in this line
    let boardSize: number = getBoardSize()

    onMount(() => {
        console.log(boardSize)
    })
```

getting the error like - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'getBoardSize' of 'getContext(...)' as it is undefined.`